# How to pop / clean Lua call stack from C

Tags: c, lua, cunit

I want to pop / clean the Lua call stack while within a C function called from Lua. Is this possible?

**Background:**
I want my C library and its extension scripts to use the same test framework. (I am aware various unit testing tools exist for Lua. I don't care; I want one report) I'm wrapping CUnit in a thin layer of Lua. CUnit provides a choice of fatal and non-fatal test assertions. Fatal assertions cause an immediate `longjmp` out of the test and back into the framework runner. This seems like it would do bad things to the Lua VM if I did not clean the stack first.

The stack will probably look something like:

```
#0. C:   assert_wrapper_fcn(test, fatal)
#1. Lua: assert_fcn(bool)
#2. Lua: test_fcn()
#3. C:   runner(&test_fcn)
```

I want to clean up everything between #0 and #3. I know the method signatures of `test_fcn()` and `assert_fcn(bool)`, but that's it.

Comment: "*This seems like it would do bad things to the Lua VM if I did not clean the stack first.*" It will do *far worse* things than that. The call stack is the least of your concerns. Long-jumping out of the Lua interpreter (past Lua's own `setjmp`'s) is likely to break pretty much everything in Lua.

Comment: Yes that is an issue too. I have very little idea how Lua's error handling system works. Really, I should have phrased the question in terms of resetting the state of the interpreter.

Comment: You can't. Lua is not "`longjmp` over me" safe. Lua has no provisions for handling the case when an application decides to half-execute a function without its knowledge. If you want to keep your Lua interpreter in a sane state, then you need to play by Lua's rules. And that's true for pretty much any C library; you can't just randomly exit the middle of one and expect it to be content with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I'm understanding the question quite right... but to clear out Lua's stack:

```
int stackSize = lua_gettop(L);
lua_pop(L, stackSize);
```

Comment: Is this sufficient if I re-enter Lua from C later?
If I understand what you are saying, I can just nuke the stack from C to abandon the state then safely use lua_call() again. Does this clear the registry as well?

Comment: Looks like @gibbss means the C call stack, not the Lua internal values stack.

On the registry question: no, that does not clear the registry (which is separate from the stack, that's why it's referred through a _pseudo_-index), but the point of the registry is that it is a table that you can edit from C and that survives between Lua-C transitions.

Comment: This is an accurate answer to the question asked, though apparently the approach I proposed has some serious problems.

Answer (score 8):

To empty the stack is really easy. Just use `lua_settop` with 0 as argument.

```
lua_settop(L, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion is to use Lua's own assert system, and then trap that in your runner and then forward the error to your unit testing framework:

Launch your Lua code with `lua_pcall`.

From within your Lua code, trigger fatal errors with the standard `assert` command.

From where you launched your Lua code, check the result of `lua_pcall` and when you get != 0, trigger your CUnit fatal assertion failure.

This will avoid mixing any longjmp's between Lua and CUnit.

Comment: This is not a bad idea -- and with a little work the error handler can still report Lua line numbers.